# Can elephants be allergic to peanuts?

Tags: allergies

Can elephants be allergic to peanuts? If yes, what is the reaction? Does the trunk swell up? I tried googling the issue but the only thing I found was a children's book about Eppie the Elephant. I realize elephants are not particularly fond of peanuts.